# How to add custom properties to leaflet 0.7.7 marker?

Tags: leaflet

I want to be able to add properties to markers in leaflet 0.7.7.

I tried:

```
var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]);
marker.properties = {};
marker.properties.someprop = "Test"
var addedMarker = marker.addTo(mymap);
// console.log the addedMarker here does not show any properties
```

when I console.log the addedMarker, I do not see the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly for me, see http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/nata/edit?html,console .

Comment: Add the marker to the map. Then try to access the "properties" from the marker that has been added to the map or layergroup.

Comment: Works perfectly, see the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VfxORp9yexVaaYABCS6F?p=preview

Comment: The playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I just facing a similar problem. I needed to store some information in the market and recover later by clicking on it. I put information on arbritrary variable in options curly brackets:

```
L.marker([lat,lon], {video:webrtc})
```

I later recovered it like this:

```
.on('click', function(e) { console.log(e.target.options['video'] )}
```